# ListView and android:id/empty

Tags: android, android-listview

I've an activity with a ListView. When there are no items to show in the ListView, I want to show a TextView with a message "No elements found". So I add a TextView with the "android:id/empty" id.

```
<ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
           />

<TextView android:id="@android:id/empty"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:text="@string/noSeHanEncontradoConsumos"
           android:gravity="center"  
           android:visibility="gone"             
           />
```

My problem is when the user selects an item of the list. I want to show the element details in another activity, show I start a new activity. But before the "details" actitity is shown, the elements of the list disappear, and the message "No elements found" is shown.

What could I do?

Thanks

Comment: What do you exactly want!!! do you want to show the textView or want to hide it.

Comment: Please post the relevant Java code, XML code and any logcat errors.

Comment: There are no errors. Is just than the textview with @android:id/empty should not be shown because the list is not empty. Anyway, I've update the question with the layout of the ListActivity

Comment: Are you destroying or resetting the list in onPause method, or the onListItemClick of your activity?

Comment: In onListItemClick method I am starting the "details" activit. In the onPause method I'm closing the cursor with the elements that are shown in the ListView.